# How do I use a method in a simple_form input without submitting it in the form?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms, simple-form

Ok, this should be on here already somewhere, but I can't find it.

I'm building a form with simple_form, and I'm using a dummy radio select input which values are based on a method (named 'simple?') in my 'Price' model. The methods looks if some attributes are used and returns false if they are. This way I can hide the advanced inputs in my form if they are not used. 
I want to use simple_form so the method is connected to the right object because more prices can be made (and created) in the same form.
I use the radio buttons (and javascript) so users can still unhide the advanced fields.

Problem is when I submit the form, the form including the :simple? method is submitted, which returns errors because it is just a method.

Question is: **How do I make sure the ':simple?' value for the is not submitted through the form, but is initiated to the right value? Or is there a smarter way of doing this?**

form.haml

```
= f.input :simple?, as: :radio, label: "Simple price?"
```

price.rb

```
  def simple?
    true unless advanced?
  end

  def advanced?
    specific_days? || period_id? || description? || begin_time? || end_time?
  end
```

Thanks for any feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you rename `simple?` to `is_simple` you can implement a virtual attribute in your model

```
def is_simple
  true unless advanced?
end

def is_simple= _ignored
  # NOOP
end

def advanced?
  specific_days? || period_id? || description? || begin_time? || end_time?
end
```

and then use :is_simple in your form

```
= f.input :is_simple, as: :radio, label: "Simple price?"
```

The renaming is necessary because `def simple?=` will lead to a syntax-error.

Comment: Cool! I also needed to add it to 'attr_accessible', but other than that it worked like a charm! Thanks, would not have found this myself. Would you happen to know where this stuff is documented?
Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to hear my answer was helpful. I use 'Virtual Attributes' a lot when a field in a form should trigger some action in the controller or model but not get stored as a value itself. When I remember right, the first time I heard about VA was here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/16-virtual-attributes in one of the very first RailsCasts.